# Git link folder from repo A to repo B

Tags: git, github

I have two repositories that contain nodejs projects.
The project structure is similar in both repositories.

- Source/

  - Models
  - Services
  - Other folders...

The models folder contains the exact same code and i am wondering if theres a solution to link this folder between the two git repositories so whenever i push a commit in one repository its also updated in the same.

So what i would like as the end result that the 
Source/models folder from repo A points to the folder source/models from repo B. And whenever the master branch is updated the changes are available in both repo without copying or messing around anything.

Symlinks dont really work since upon deplyoment the projects maybe deployed on different machines, also i would have to set up symlinks on all dev computers hich is again messy. I would like to have this working with git. I looked at git subtree and submodules but couldnt figure out how to link folders inside a repo. I also dont want to create a different repo for each folder i wish to link. If its not possible then i would like to know about a better work around. I am using github.

Comment: With git, each repository is a different entity. As far as I know, linking commits between repos is not supported.

Comment: It appears that you've looked at [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), and it's this kind of scenario they're meant to address.  However, it doesn't work like Subversion, where you can pull in a particular path.  Instead, it works on whole repositories.  To use it, you'd need to re-organize things (maybe a third repo with the model code, and the other two incorporate it as a submodule), but it's definitely a choice.

Comment: @jszamaister it would be fine to have as many as repos if i could just commit to one repo and automatically update it on the other shared repo? Splitting the code up and having to commit multiple times for this is sort of equal with copying the directories before doing a commit. Can i have it automatic so i dont have to worry about this? I am wondering..

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider the following a workaround but rather a valid procedure that might end up in anyone's Git workflow.

In A repository run `git remote add b <url-to-b>` which will create a reference to B. From that point onwards you'll be able to `git checkout b/<branch-name> -- ./Source/Models`, thus obtaining contents of the folder under B's revision.

> Note: The technique may be applied bidirectionally.

Comment: Hi thanks. I have a few questions about this method. Is there a way to automatize this on my development machines? So whenever i pull the updates i can synchronize them automatically? Doing this manually after every update is sort of an annoyance. I am surprised that such scenario is not so straightforward and supported out of the box on github.